# Is is possible to open ports using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova

I need to share files using WiFi in my Android application. Is is possible to open ports using PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. Phonegap is just a wrapper around your mobile browser container. You could try using WebSockets.

Don't think Phonegap has built in support for websockets yet.
But there are some resources like this:
http://remysharp.com/2010/10/04/websockets-in-phonegap-projects/